# Convert Grails GSP custom tag to AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grails

Converting from Grails / GSP custom tag to AngularJS Directive

I have an existing Grails / GSP tag lib that will generate a link that will be displayed by a remote server, loading content from the local server. The URL in the link must be the full path. The custom GSP tag lets me specify the action right in the GSP. I need to replace this using AngularJS, and I understand that directives are the way to go.  Is there an easy way to pass parameters from
the tag in a GSP into the directive?

Are there equivalent functions to the "grailsLinkGenerator" that I can use to generate the URL inside the directive?

My existing Grails / GSP tag looks something like this:

GSP:

```
<g:myRemoteLink action="alpha" update="targetDiv" id="${ent.id}" >Show Alpha</g:myRemoteLink>
```

MyTagLib.groovy:

```
def myRemoteLink = { attrs, body ->
  def link = g.remoteLink( attrs, body )
  def fullLink = link.replace( grailsLinkGenerator.contextPath, grailsLinkGenerator.serverBaseURL )
  out << fullLink.toString()
}
```

---

I need to convert it over to load/display the remote content in a ng-switch like this:

```
<div ng-switch-when='alpha' ><div alpha-directive></div></div>
```

So far I came up with this directive, but there must be a better way? Is there something like the grails link generator in AngularJS? I still need to pass in the ID to be appended to the URL.

```
app.directive('alphaDirective', function() {
  var id = $scope.id;
  var baseURL = "https://myServerURL/";
  var controller = "admin";
  var action = "alpha";
  var path = "'" + baseURL + "/" + controller + "/" + action + "/" + id + "'";
  return {
    template: "<div ng-include=\"" + path + "\"></div>"
  };
});
```

Comment: What parameters do you want passed? I use grails and angular and I think I can help but I'm having a hard time knowing exactly what you want generated.

Comment: It just needs to have an ID passed in from a select in the GSP. Basically the user is selecting which content to display. The old pure GSP code just passed it into the custom tag as a param with id=${ent.id}, but in the new AngularJS code, the id is coming from an input, and needs to be appended to the template URL. I agree with Christopher's answer below, that its bad to have the javascript generate the URL. I am new to AngularJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, generating the absolute path to a grails action isn't just a `GSP` function. It's a Grails function. But you really don't want to be mixing up those two. Your Grails should be on the back end and your Angular should be on the front end and attempting to blur the two is going to end in maintenance hell.

So I'd recommend firstly, creating an endpoint using `grailsLinkGenerator`. You pass in the name of the desired `action` and it returns the full URL.

```
def absoluteLink(String action) {
    // Return the absolute path for the action.
}
```

Then you can write an angular *service* with an API method like..

```
function getAbsoluteLink(action) {
    // AJAX request to the server.
}
```

Then simply have the directive make the request to the service, and you've got a directive that can convert the name of an action into the full path, without needing to build up a String and without needing to mix up the responsibilities of your front end and your back end.

AND, if you decide to change the structure of your API, you won't need to change how the URL is created.